# Why am I not able to type input into input boxes?

Tags: html, css

### To replicate:

- Be using Chrome version 34 or the latest version of Firefox.
- Open up the site and click `Sign Up` or `Login`
- In Chrome, click in a `password` input.  In Firefox, click in any input.

The results should be that the input appears to get focus, but does not allow the user to enter characters.

### Solutions I have tried:

- Disabling JavaScript
- Messing with the `z-index` settings (making sure that the parent and child elements had a `position` other than `static`.

### Things to note:

- I did not have this problem in Chrome version 33.
- This happens in Windows 7, Windows 8.1, and on Mac.
- In Chrome only the inputs of type `password` do not work.  Only `text` does.

I really feel like it's an issue with the `z-index` and the `.list` elements underneath the `.drop-box`, but am also puzzled why (in Chrome) an input with type text would work but password wouldn't.  I have been trying to see what might have changed between Chrome version 33 and 34 so I can maybe pinpoint the issue, but have had no luck as of yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your code in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `box-sizing: border-box` and `padding-top + padding-bottom = height`. This means the content height is zero, so you cannot see anything you type (but attempting to type correctly updates the validation).

You should remove the `box-sizing` on those elements, or remove the `padding`.

Comment: Well that was too simple.  Solved my issue.  Don't know why Chrome would choose to do this on `password` inputs and not `text`.  Thanks.